# AWS S3 static website: Error 400: The specified bucket exists in another region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created static website http://librarysystest.bi.nu in AWS S3. The bucket `librarysystest.bi.nu` was created by cloudformation. The website contains video which can be accessed via URL: https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/librarysystest.bi.nu/7Ys_yKGNFRQ.webm

I have created A-Record in Route53 `librarysystest.bi.nu` pointing to `s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com.`

But the URL http://librarysystest.bi.nu/7Ys_yKGNFRQ.webm gives me the error

> 400 Bad Request
>   Code: IncorrectEndpoint
>   Message: The specified bucket exists in another region. Please direct requests to the specified endpoint.
>   Endpoint: librarysystest.bi.nu.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
>   RequestId: 602764FBC4BD93D4
>   HostId: N1EOt05Qfrc/u/+ny/ADfOY0Vvmr/Tg4oqFBiY/Wfv9h2hznGicyj8pOI4MsY5YocexGrhd/D90=

I have created static websites before but this is the first time I am facing a problem. Can someone spot the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue soon as I posted the question. I didnt add the `index.html`, didn't think that was important. Curiously, I added the file and (*abracadabra*) it worked.

This is for someone who might be scratching his/her head for hours.. like I did :)